# SWI-Prolog CLPFD

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm new to prolog for constraint programming. I have an issue with CLPFD not reducing a domain as I expect it to. This is probably really simple.

```
 [A,B] ins 1..5,A*B#=5.
```

I expect it to reduce the domain of A and B to

```
1\/5
```

But it just gives

```
A in 1..5,
A*B#=5,
B in 1..5.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

While this answer is tailored to [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) as implemented in [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), the idea/method is portable.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Here's how we can *reduce domain sizes before starting full enumeration*:

```
shave_zs(Zs) :-
   maplist(flag_zs_shave_z(F,Zs), Zs),
   once((var(F) ; ground(Zs) ; shave_zs(Zs))).

flag_zs_shave_z(Flag, Zs, Z) :-
   (  fd_size(Z, sup)
   -> true                                    % never shave the infinite
   ;  fd_dom(Z, Z_dom),
      phrase(dom_integers_(Z_dom), Z_vals),
      maplist(flag_zs_z_val(Flag,Zs,Z), Z_vals)
   ).

flag_zs_z_val(Flag, Zs, Z, Z_val) :-
   (  \+ call_with_inference_limit((Z #= Z_val,labeling([],Zs)), 1000, _)
   -> Z #\= Z_val,
      Flag = true
   ;  true
   ).
```

We use grammar `dom_integers_//1`, as defined on the SWI-Prolog [clpfd manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

```
dom_integers_(I)      --> { integer(I) }, [I].
dom_integers_(L..U)   --> { numlist(L, U, Is) }, Is.
dom_integers_(D1\/D2) --> dom_integers_(D1), dom_integers_(D2).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- [A,B] ins 1..5,  A*B #= 5,  (Shaved = false ; Shaved = true, shave_zs([A,B])).
Shaved = false, A*B #= 5, A in 1..5, B in 1..5 ;
Shaved =  true, A*B #= 5, A in 1\/5, B in 1\/5.

?- [A,B] ins 1..10, A*B #= 10, (Shaved = false ; Shaved = true, shave_zs([A,B])).
Shaved = false, A*B #= 10, A in 1..10      , B in 1..10 ;
Shaved =  true, A*B #= 10, A in 1..2\/5\/10, B in 1..2\/5\/10.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are right that `1\/5` would be optimal pruning in this case.

However, for efficiency reasons, CLP(FD) systems typically maintain only so-called *bounds consistency* for arithmetic constraints, and in general do not remove interior elements from domains even when some of them cannot participate in solutions.

*Bounds consistency*, in the finite case, means that there are solutions where the variable assumes the lower and upper boundary of the domain. In this case, there are solutions for `A=1` and `A=5`.

Notice that these are the only solutions in this concrete case, but in general, there are also solutions with interior points in analogous larger instances, for example:

```
?- [A,B] ins 1..10, A*B#=10, label([A,B]).
A = 1,
B = 10 ;
A = 2,
B = 5 ;
A = 5,
B = 2 ;
A = 10,
B = 1.
```

The good news though is that the *number* of such solutions only grows logarithmically in the size of the domain:

```
?- length(_, Exp), N #= 2^Exp, [A,B] ins 1..N,A*B#=N,
   findall(., label([A,B]), Ls), length(Ls, L),
   writeln(Exp-L), false.
0-1
1-2
2-3
3-4
4-5
5-6
6-7
7-8
etc.
```

This is in contrast to other cases, like `X mod 2 #= 0`, where the number of solutions grows *linearly* in the size of the domain of `X` (and thus *exponentially* in the length of its decimal representation), and it is thus not feasible to explicitly prune the domain.

Thus, as a feasible workaround, you can use `label/1` to obtain concrete solutions, and then use `in/2` constraints to restrict the operands to their concretely admissible domains:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

stricter_domains(Vs) :-
        findall(Vs, label(Vs), Sols0),
        transpose(Sols0, Sols),
        maplist(list_to_domain, Sols, Ds),
        maplist(in, Vs, Ds).

list_to_domain([L|Ls], Dom) :- foldl(dom_disj, Ls, L, Dom).

dom_disj(D0, I, D0\/I).
```

Your example:

```
?- [A,B] ins 1..5, A*B#=5, stricter_domains([A,B]).
A in 1\/5,
A*B#=5,
B in 1\/5.
```

Comment: Why no mentioning of `contracting/1`?

Comment: Agree, but what about ruling out values one-by-one? Similar to contracting.

Comment: @false. We need a proper interface. Let clpfd export `contracting/1`, or maybe better `contracting/2` :) The domain reductions are interesting for multiple reasons: First, they are an additional tool in the toolbox. clpfd-users may already have a similar idea like this (but struggle to realize a decent implementation). Second, it helps characterize *problems*: how many sudoku, nonogram, and other puzzles (that people solve for fun) are *completely* solvable by `contracting/2` alone--- without ever using `labeling/2! Oh, and third, a perfect fit for multicores (*no state* needs to be shared!)

Comment: Why don't **you** write an answer?

Comment: Please also check out the literature: I think our "contracting" is called "shaving" in the CLP(FD) literature.