# Does the predicate `contracting/1` restore deleted inconsistent values?

Tags: dynamic, prolog, clpfd

This question is subsequent to another one [I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36260440/2936460) on custom labeling in Prolog.

Does the `contracting/1` predicate, when used after a value assignment to a variable in a custom labeling predicate, delete the "inconsistent" values from the domain permanently ? Or are these values restored when backtracking ?

Comment: From a purely declarative viewpoint, there is no need to restore  inconsistent values. But `contracting/1` might blow ob the representation of the domain so much that it becomes infeasible to use. Or the domain representation leads to an even more costly search thereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are of course **restored** on backtracking.

It is the nature of **pure** Prolog predicates, such as CLP(FD) constraints, that everything they state is completely **undone** on backtracking. Without this, many important declarative properties would not hold. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information.

You can see easily that this also holds for `clpfd:contracting/1`, using for example a sample session:

```
?- X in 0..5, X mod Y #= 2, Y in 0..2.
X in 0..5,
X mod Y#=2,
Y in 1..2.

?- X in 0..5, X mod Y #= 2, Y in 0..2, clpfd:contracting([X,Y]).
false.

?- X in 0..5, X mod Y #= 2, Y in 0..2, ( clpfd:contracting([X,Y]) ; true ).
X in 0..5,
X mod Y#=2,
Y in 1..2.
```