# Optimizing clp(FD) labeling

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I have been crunching through a scheduling problem following [this article](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/open-source-technology-insights/solving-logical-business-problems-using-prolog-part-3/) which references [this program](https://github.com/mjones-credera/prolog-samples/blob/master/shift_scheduler_clp.pl) and trying to generalize it past the seven shifts. I am getting hung up on the labelling strategy employed because I am not sure how it could be optimized to report results in a reasonable time frame.

The gist is, a map is generated of all the combinations of staff (s), shifts to fill (f), and tasks (t) to be performed on each shift, which results in s*f*t variables which then are either labeled 1 or 0 to represent assigned or not assigned.

The example uses 3 staff, with 11 shifts with several tasks per shift and runs really fast to generate a possible solution.

But labelling takes an unreasonable amount of time when even considering as few as 20 shifts with 1 task per shift with 6 staff.

Is this normal in the sense I should expect this performance loss with this increased complexity?

Is there a more elegant strategy I could look at to employ?

---

Dec 19 edit:

Looking into this more, I think the problem is that labelling in this context is inefficient since I don't know how to create a ranking mechanism to assist the default labelling strategy since the map is dealing with reified (with a domain of 0..1) variables.

I think my options are:

a) add some variable to assist the labeling strategy to make it so it behaves better than a bruteforce strategy.

b) create a custom labeling strategy. (any resources on this would be appreciated)

-- The code:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- dynamic employee/1.
:- dynamic employee_max_shifts/2.
:- dynamic employee_skill/2.
:- dynamic task_skills/2.
:- dynamic employee_unavailable/2.
:- dynamic task/2.
:- dynamic employee_assigned/2.

employee(micah).
employee(jonathan).
employee(blake).
employee(barry).
employee(jerry).
employee(larry).
employee(gary).

employee_max_shifts(micah,      14).
employee_max_shifts(jonathan,   14).
employee_max_shifts(blake,      14).
employee_max_shifts(barry,      14).
employee_max_shifts(jerry,      14).
employee_max_shifts(larry,      14).
employee_max_shifts(gary,       14).

employee_skill(micah,   programming).
employee_skill(barry,   programming).
employee_skill(jerry,   programming).
employee_skill(larry,   programming).
employee_skill(gary,    programming).
employee_skill(jonathan,programming).
employee_skill(blake,   programming).

task_skills(web_design,[programming]).

shifts([
    shift(1,1),shift(1,2),
    shift(2,1),shift(2,2),
    shift(3,1),shift(3,2),
    shift(4,1),shift(4,2),
    shift(5,1),shift(5,2),
    shift(6,1),shift(6,2),
    shift(7,1),shift(7,2),
    shift(8,1),shift(8,2),
    shift(9,1),shift(9,2),
    shift(10,1),shift(10,2),
    shift(11,1),shift(11,2),
    shift(12,1),shift(12,2),
    shift(13,1),shift(13,2),
    shift(14,1),shift(14,2),
    shift(15,1),shift(15,2),
    shift(16,1),shift(16,2),
    shift(17,1),shift(17,2),
    shift(18,1),shift(18,2),
    shift(19,1),shift(19,2),
    shift(20,1),shift(20,2),
    shift(21,1),shift(21,2),
    shift(22,1),shift(22,2),
    shift(23,1),shift(23,2),
    shift(24,1),shift(24,2),
    shift(25,1),shift(25,2),
    shift(26,1),shift(26,2),
    shift(27,1),shift(27,2),
    shift(28,1),shift(28,2)]).

task(web_design,shift('1',1)).
task(web_design,shift('1',2)).
task(web_design,shift('2',1)).
task(web_design,shift('2',2)).
task(web_design,shift('3',1)).
task(web_design,shift('3',2)).
task(web_design,shift('4',1)).
task(web_design,shift('4',2)).
task(web_design,shift('6',1)).
task(web_design,shift('6',2)).
task(web_design,shift('7',1)).
task(web_design,shift('7',2)).
task(web_design,shift('8',1)).
task(web_design,shift('8',2)).
task(web_design,shift('9',1)).
task(web_design,shift('9',2)).
task(web_design,shift('10',1)).
task(web_design,shift('10',2)).
task(web_design,shift('11',1)).
task(web_design,shift('11',2)).
task(web_design,shift('12',1)).
task(web_design,shift('12',2)).
task(web_design,shift('13',1)).
task(web_design,shift('13',2)).
task(web_design,shift('14',1)).
task(web_design,shift('14',2)).
task(web_design,shift('15',1)).
task(web_design,shift('15',2)).
task(web_design,shift('16',1)).
task(web_design,shift('16',2)).
task(web_design,shift('17',1)).
task(web_design,shift('17',2)).
task(web_design,shift('18',1)).
task(web_design,shift('18',2)).
task(web_design,shift('19',1)).
task(web_design,shift('19',2)).
task(web_design,shift('20',1)).
task(web_design,shift('20',2)).
task(web_design,shift('21',1)).
task(web_design,shift('21',2)).
task(web_design,shift('22',1)).
task(web_design,shift('22',2)).
task(web_design,shift('23',1)).
task(web_design,shift('23',2)).
task(web_design,shift('24',1)).
task(web_design,shift('24',2)).
task(web_design,shift('25',1)).
task(web_design,shift('25',2)).
task(web_design,shift('26',1)).
task(web_design,shift('26',2)).
task(web_design,shift('27',1)).
task(web_design,shift('27',2)).
task(web_design,shift('28',1)).
task(web_design,shift('28',2)).

% get_employees(-Employees)
get_employees(Employees) :-
    findall(employee(E),employee(E),Employees).
% get_tasks(-Tasks)
get_tasks(Tasks) :-
    findall(task(TName,TShift),task(TName,TShift),Tasks).

% create_assoc_list(+Employees,+Tasks,-Assoc)
% Find all combinations of pairs and assign each a variable to track
create_assoc_list(Es,Ts,Assoc) :-
    empty_assoc(EmptyAssoc),
    findall(assign(E,T),(member(E,Es),member(T,Ts)),AssignmentPairs),
    build_assoc_list(EmptyAssoc,AssignmentPairs,Assoc).

% build_assoc_list(+AssocAcc,+Pairs,-Assoc)
build_assoc_list(Assoc,[],Assoc).
build_assoc_list(AssocAcc,[Pair|Pairs],Assoc) :-
    put_assoc(Pair,AssocAcc,_Var,AssocAcc2),
    build_assoc_list(AssocAcc2,Pairs,Assoc).

% assoc_keys_vars(+Assoc,+Keys,-Vars)
%
% Retrieves all Vars from Assoc corresponding to Keys.
% (Note: At first it seems we could use a fancy findall in place of this, but findall
% will replace the Vars with new variable references, which ruins our map.)
assoc_keys_vars(Assoc, Keys, Vars) :-
        maplist(assoc_key_var(Assoc), Keys, Vars).
assoc_key_var(Assoc, Key, Var) :- get_assoc(Key, Assoc, Var).

% list_or(+Exprs,-Disjunction)
list_or([L|Ls], Or) :- foldl(disjunction_, Ls, L, Or).
disjunction_(A, B, B#\/A).

get_assoc_values_in_employee_order(Es, Ts, Assoc, Values) :-
    findall(assign(E,T),(member(E,Es), member(T,Ts)),AssignmentPairs),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc, AssignmentPairs,Values).

% schedule(-Schedule)
%
% Uses clp(fd) to generate a schedule of assignments, as a list of assign(Employee,Task)
% elements. Adheres to the following rules:
% (1) Every task must have at least one employee assigned to it.
% (2) No employee may be assigned to multiple tasks in the same shift.
% (3) No employee may be assigned to more than their maximum number of shifts.
% (4) No employee may be assigned to a task during a shift in which they are unavailable.
% (5) No employee may be assigned to a task for which they lack necessary skills.
% (6) Any pre-existing assignments (employee_assigned) must still hold.
schedule(Schedule) :-
    writeln('Building constraints'),
    get_employees(Es),
    get_tasks(Ts),
    create_assoc_list(Es,Ts,Assoc),
    assoc_to_keys(Assoc,AssocKeys),
    assoc_to_values(Assoc,AssocValues),
    constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),

    label(AssocValues),

    findall(AssocKey,(member(AssocKey,AssocKeys),get_assoc(AssocKey,Assoc,1)),Assignments),
    Schedule = Assignments.

% constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    core_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),
    simul_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),
    max_shifts_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),
    unavailable_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),
    skills_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts),
    assigned_constraints(Assoc).

% core_constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
%
% Builds the main conjunctive sequence of the form:
% (A_e(0),t(0) \/ A_e(1),t(0) \/ ...) /\ (A_e(0),t(1) \/ A_e(1),t(1) \/ ...) /\ ...
core_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    maplist(core_constraints_disj(Assoc,Es),Ts).

% core_constraints_disj(+Assoc,+Employees,+Task)
% Helper for core_constraints, builds a disjunction of sub-expressions, such that
% at least one employee must be assigned to Task
core_constraints_disj(Assoc,Es,T) :-
    findall(assign(E,T),member(E,Es),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    list_or(Vars,Disj),
    Disj.


% simul_constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
%
% Builds a constraint expression to prevent one person from being assigned to multiple
% tasks at the same time. Of the form:
% (A_e(0),t(n1) + A_e(0),t(n2) + ... #=< 1) /\ (A_e(1),t(n1) + A_e(1),t(n2) + ... #=< 1)
% where n1,n2,etc. are indices of tasks that occur at the same time.
simul_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    shifts(Shifts),
    findall(employee_shift(E,Shift),(member(E,Es),member(Shift,Shifts)),EmployeeShifts),
    maplist(simul_constraints_subexpr(Assoc,Ts),EmployeeShifts).

simul_constraints_subexpr(Assoc,Ts,employee_shift(E,Shift)) :-
    findall(task(TName,Shift),member(task(TName,Shift),Ts),ShiftTs),
    findall(assign(E,T),member(T,ShiftTs),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    sum(Vars,#=<,1).


% max_shifts_constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
%
% Builds a constraint expression that prevents employees from being assigned too many
% shifts. Of the form:
% (A_e(0),t(0) + A_e(0),t(1) + ... #=< M_e(0)) /\ (A_e(1),t(0) + A_e(1),t(1) + ... #=< M_e(1)) /\ ...
% where M_e(n) is the max number of shifts for employee n.
max_shifts_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    maplist(max_shifts_subexpr(Assoc,Ts),Es).

max_shifts_subexpr(Assoc,Ts,E) :-
    E = employee(EName),
    employee_max_shifts(EName,MaxShifts),
    findall(assign(E,T),member(T,Ts),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    sum(Vars,#=,MaxShifts).


% unavailable_constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
%
% For every shift for which an employee e(n) is unavailable, add a constraint of the form
% A_e(n),t(x) = 0 for every t(x) that occurs during that shift. Note that 0 is equivalent
% to False in clp(fd).
unavailable_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    findall(assign(E,T),(
            member(E,Es),
            E = employee(EName),
            employee_unavailable(EName,Shift),
            member(T,Ts),
            T = task(_TName,Shift)
        ),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    maplist(#=(0),Vars).


% skills_constraints(+Assoc,+Employees,+Tasks)
%
% For every task t(m) for which an employee e(n) lacks sufficient skills, add a
% constraint of the form A_e(n),t(m) = 0.
skills_constraints(Assoc,Es,Ts) :-
    findall(assign(E,T),(
            member(T,Ts),
            T = task(TName,_TShift),
            task_skills(TName,TSkills),
            member(E,Es),
            \+employee_has_skills(E,TSkills)
        ),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    maplist(#=(0),Vars).


% employee_has_skills(+Employee,+Skills)
%
% Fails if Employee does not possess all Skills.
employee_has_skills(employee(EName),Skills) :-
    findall(ESkill,employee_skill(EName,ESkill),ESkills),
    subset(Skills,ESkills).


% assigned_constraints(+Assoc)
%
% For every task t(m) to which an employee e(n) is already assigned, add a constraint
% of the form A_e(n),t(m) = 1 to force the assignment into the schedule. Note that
% we execute this constraint inline here instead of collecting it into a Constraint list.
assigned_constraints(Assoc) :-
    findall(assign(E,T),(
            employee_assigned(EName,T),
            E = employee(EName)
        ),Keys),
    assoc_keys_vars(Assoc,Keys,Vars),
    maplist(#=(1),Vars).




task_skills(web_design,[programming]).
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a performance problem and not some looping? Temporally replace `labeling/2` by `false` just to see if your program terminates. See [tag:failure-slice] for more.

Comment: I believe it is, I replaced the label with a false, and it terminates promptly. I have further suspicion towards labelling performance because when I interrupt the program and trace the call stack it's working through clp predicates.

Comment: Since I am using SWI prolog for this, I have read that it is right that I should expect it to terminate if it makes it to the label stage, is that correct? Is there a way to see in the trace or call stack what the current state of the label variables are?

Comment: You are right: `library(clpfd)` in SWI has the guarantee that `labeling/2` always terminates.

Comment: As for a trace: This will certainly confuse you more that you might think. But you could try to label some variables first and then the others etc.

Comment: I think based on this, I know there only a handful of labelling sub patterns that will be accepted by the constraints, is there an approach to take where I could label several other unknowns based on the labelled value of the current variable?  Following this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36266040/8583288) I believe I could create a custom label predicate, but how do i assign the values to make use of backtracking?

Comment: At least, take into account the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261381/772868), too!